# what will happen if add screenOrientation=behind into launch Activity element

Tags: android, android-layout

what will  happen  if  add  screenOrientation=behind  into  launch Activity element

```
   <activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="behind"
            android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation|keyboard"
            android:noHistory="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

I want  to  know  what  will  happen  if   I  write this ,  and  want  to know  the  details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are set all activity of your project in the same screenOrientation. you can start your application with a splash screen activity, set the orientation like in your current code and forward to your CoreActivity or any other activity in your App.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` set

```
<activity
    android:name=".CoreActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="behind"/>
```

This will use the same orientation as the activity that's immediately beneath it in the activity stack.

Explicitly it's used to Keep the screen in the same orientation as whatever is behind this activity.

Comment: but  lauch activity  has not  orientation , if  I add  screenOrientation=behind in lauch-acitivity  what's its  orientation?

Comment: If auto-rotation is ON, Then activity ignores "behind" attribute and rotates with the phone screen.

Comment: AutoRotation in system settings is off (or is on - it doesn't matter, "behind" option is ignored anyway). android:screenOrientation="landscape" is set for MainActivity, and android:screenOrientation="behind" is set for SecondActivity, which means that SecondActivity must be launched in landscape orientation too.